# how many spaces are considered in \t

Tags: c++, c

why the  number of space is different in case 3
how the result is getting effected by \t character.

(-) refers space by (\t)

```
case 1
 void main()
    {
        int a,b;
        printf("%d",printf("hello%d\t",scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)));
    }
```

here the output is>hello2-7

```
case 2
 void main()
    {
        int a,b;
        printf("%d",printf("hello\t%d",scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)));
    }
```

here the output is>hello-27

```
case 3
 void main()
    {
        int a,b;
        printf("%d",printf("\thello%d",scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)));
    }
```

here the output is>--------hello27
Why in the 3rd case there are 8 spaces.

Comment: The output is different because you are putting `\t` at different places in `printf()`.

Comment: i want to know how the result is getting effected by \t character

Comment: first of all "affected" not effected,secondly i don't understand your question.how it is affected means what?? it is built to to do so,wherever you are including the `\t` it is printing the tab sequence .

Comment: kindly read the question first. Why there are 8 spaces in the last case.

Comment: On my system the answer isn't different,it always show the tab wherever it is put.

Comment: In case1 and case 2 , it is considering \t as single space while in case 3 , it prints h after 8 spaces.

Comment: @pallavi That's the behavior of TAB, the display fills up spaces up to the next TAB mark. Where the TAB marks are defined depends on the terminal program or whatever is used to render the text.

Comment: so if inside the text it will take one space , else at start or at the end it will take 8 space (according to my terminal) ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Most* terminal programs will have a tab stop at every 8th column - so I'd expect output to be determined like this (I know your output's a little different - discussed below):

```
.                                column
.                                   1         2
input                      12345678901234567890
"%d",printf("hello%d\t"    hello2__7
"%d",printf("hello\t%d"    hello___27
"%d",printf("\thello%d"    ________hello27
```

To understand this, you have to understand the order of evaluation of your (unnecessarily complex) code.  Examining the first `printf` line...

```
printf("%d",printf("hello%d\t",scanf("%d%d",&a,&b)));
```

Above, the *arguments* to the *left-hand* `printf` have to be prepared before it can print anything itself, and those arguments include the result of calling the *right-hand* `printf`.  That right-hand `printf` outputs `hello`, the number of arguments `scanf` read from standard input which is 2 if you typed two, then the tab, then the right-hand `printf` has finished outputting and returns "7" to indicate how many characters it printed, which is printed by the left-hand `printf`.  I would expect a tab to take you to the 9th column on screen, which suggests TWO spaces before the 7, where-as your question says you're observing 1.  Clearly your terminal works a little  different, probably considering the 8th, 16th, 24th etc. columns to be tab stops.

### More about tabs

There is no universal interpretation of the `\t` TAB character... how it's rendered depends on the terminal software or rendering device you're using (e.g. an xterm, vt220, vt100 terminal, MS-DOS command window, printer, IDE, text editor etc.).

Some display/printing/formatting programs will consider there to be a tab stop every N characters, where N is often 8, such that if you issue a tab from the first column through to the 8th column you're taken to the 9th, a tab from the 9th to 16th column takes you to the 17th etc..  But, many programs will have ways to set arbitrary columns for tab placements.  Some programs like MS Word can use variable-width fonts with which the number of characters between tab stops varies: if your C++ program prints some text that you import into Word you may find it practically impossible to work out how many tabs are needed to get the desired alignment of output - it's generally easier to just put one tab between values and change your tab stops inside Word so it all looks ok, or stick to a fixed-width font such as Courier.

C++ IDEs often let you set the value ("N" above) for columns per tab stop - 4 and 8 are both common settings, with 8 often meaning your source code indentation is a mix of tabs and spaces to reach the desired left-hand-column: that's kind of messy to navigate with naive cursor movement implementation.  Many people prefer to set a "insert spaces when tab is pressed" option so the file is always saved with actual spaces, and displays more predictably with a wide variety of display/printing software.

Answer (score 7):

A TAB has only the space given to it as it is rendered (so does any character, really); however, one subtle difference with tabs is that they are often taken to mean *advance to the next "virtual column"* (I'm sure there is a better term), where these virtual columns are, say, 8 characters wide; although this width can often be changed.

Here is an ugly graphic, where `n..-` represents a "virtual column" and `T..t` represents the space "taken up" by the tab:

```
                1-------2-------3-------
hello\tworld    helloTttworld
\thelloworld    Tttttttthelloworld
hello\t\tworld  helloTttTtttttttworld
```

Comment: then how to decide in exam what should be the correct output ?

Comment: @pallavi A tab will display with as many spaces as needed for the next column position to be divisible by 8. If a tab is at position 7, it will show up as one space. If it is at position 11, it will show up as five spaces. If it is already at a position divisible with 8, it will show up as the full 8 spaces.

Answer (score 6):

in C99 and C11,

> \t ( horizontal tab ) Moves the active position to the next horizontal
>   tabulation position on the current line. If the active position is at
>   or past the last defined horizontal tabulation position, the behavior
>   of the display device is unspecified.

while C++03 and C++11 don't specify the difference of '\t' with C.

Comment: I didn't expect this to be defined under C by any means!

Answer (score 5):

`\t` does not contain any space. `\t` is a proper character that could be displayed with different length, but it's only one char.

Answer (score 0):

As per compiler and computer software width would be changing either 4bits or 8 bits For example: here is c program compiled using compiler gcc 6.3 compiler on windows 10 pro where width 4 bits has taken,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
printf("a12345678patil\n");
printf("a\tpat\til");
}
```

output:

```
a12345678patil
a   pat il
```