# is \t only considered 1 character?

Tags: c#

I was trying to do some basic logic with a do while and substring like below

```
bool foundFirstTaskname = false;
int startCounter = 0;
do
{
    var checkEveryTwo = name.Substring(startCounter, 1);
    if (checkEveryTwo == "\t")
        startCounter += 1;        
    else
        foundFirstTaskname = true;

} while (!foundFirstTaskname);
```

I run a little code like this when a user does a paste action so I grab the contents of the clipboard and set them to 'name'. Now for this application, I am checking for "\t" since they can be pasting things from excel for instance.

Lets say, our pasted input for this example is - \t\t\t\tTest1. (this would happen by adding contents to cell e1 and copying a-e1 and pasting it into this app.)

Now I my little do while is just searching for the first instance where there is no \t, and it hits the bool flag.

Now for my actual question, when I run this app and I look at my checkEveryTwo variable, if it actually sub string the \t, it displays that in the var variable, that is good.

so now my variable has displayed \t, \t, \t, \t, but now when it gets to the remainder of the string, it will only display 'T'.

Why is that? I know I am using a start counter of 0, and increment by 1 which is why I get the 'T', but why am I still getting back "\t" every time then if I am increment by 1.

Is "\t" considered only 1 character?
I also checked this post out, which doesn't seem to be related to my specific question.
[how many spaces are considered in \t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269109/how-many-spaces-are-considered-in-t)

ps. sorry for long post, wanted to make sure people understood my question fully.

Comment: Please pay attention to the preview when posting - there was no reason for your code to be all the way over to the right.

Comment: The code you've given doesn't *display* anything - and seems to be basically just finding the first character which *isn't* a tab. Is that really all you want?

Comment: Exactly, its just to find the first character which is not a tab. That's all this is used for, but I don't understand why this behavior is acting the way it is as mentioned in the op.

Comment: For a bit of clarification, `\t` *is* **one character**, but it *is not* **one space**. It is however many pixels whatever displays it wants to display it as, which is 0 to infinity. Relating it to spaces in any way only results in issues.

Comment: Okay - there are simple ways to do that without taking `Substring` etc. Use the indexer on `string` to find a single character. Don't forget that you're explicitly saying that `checkEveryTwo` is one character long, so you shouldn't be surprised that it's `T` rather than `Test1`.

Comment: From what I understood, you want to find first name, if any. In this case, `\t` isn't the only white-space separator may appear in there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, `\t` is considered to be a single character.  That it can represent multiple spaces on a screen is a function of the program which chooses to do that, but the tab character only occupies the space of a single character.

Comment: Escaped characters are a fundamental feature of strings in every programming language I can think of. It would be faster for you to look them up.

Comment: @user258738 yes. See the MSDN article on character literals for full details. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087.aspx