# C# string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\t") == true

Tags: c#

I have a line of code

```
var delimiter = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foundDelimiter) ? "," : foundDelimiter;
```

when `foundDelimiter` is `"\t"`, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace returns true.

Why? And what is the approriate way to work around this?

Comment: If you're not looking for whitespace, use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(...)`

Comment: I do not understand why this was down voted, it's an honest mistake.

Comment: **Why** do you want to work around it? Its clear that you want to replace whitespace, tab is whitespace just like a regular space character.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but this is about as fundamental as "Why does `Console.Writeline("Hello World!");` put "Hello World!" in my console?"

Comment: @Magus: I didn't realize that the tab character was interpreted as whitespace. I assumed that it was it's own character.

Comment: @Magus, Not a perfect example, It is still something that can confuse developers with bit of experience.

Comment: See [White-Space Characters - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9a023cx.aspx) `Space, tab, linefeed, carriage-return, formfeed, vertical-tab, and newline characters are called "white-space characters" `

Comment: @sabe Additionally you might like to know that you can avoid escape sequences by adding @ in front of the string like this `string s = @"\t"`

Comment: @toplel32: I'm not trying to clear whitespace. I'm allowing a user to enter a delimiter to use for creating a file. And since a tab is a valid delimiter (but whitespace isn't), I had assumed that `\t` was it's own character.

Comment: @Sabe it is, but not to visual studio. User input will be treated literally.

Comment: Tab is it's own character, it's simply a whitespace character. How it is displayed is totally dependent on the context.

Comment: “tab is a valid delimiter (but whitespace isn't)”? You contradict yourself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\t` is the tab character, which is whitespace. In C# can do either of these to get a tab:

```
var tab1 = "\t";
var tab2 = "    ";

var areEqual = tab1 == tab2; //returns true
```

Edit: As noted by Magus, SO is converting my tab character into spaces when the answer gets rendered. If you're in your IDE you'd just hit quote, tab, quote.

As far as a workaround goes, I'd suggest you just add a check for tabs in your conditional.

```
var delimiter = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foundDelimiter) && foundDelimiter != "\t" ? "," : foundDelimiter;
```

Comment: Also, for reference: [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx)

Comment: As viggity said the function is right. You can make an if to make it works the way you want.

Comment: then as far as Visual Studio is concerned, are `"\t"` and `"   "` completely equivalent?

Comment: @Sabe and Silvermind, SO has converted his tab to four spaces. When in edit mode, it is a tab. But yes, a tab character is generally represented as `\t` in strings in programming languages specifically so you can recognize it as such, but in C# can be used literally as well; the two are equivalent.

Comment: @Sabe No. A tab character is one character. The number of spaces which it might represent is entirely context-dependent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814800/is-t-only-considered-1-character/23814901#23814901

Comment: @ClickRick: Even saying 'number of spaces' is not totally accurate. It's a common misconception, since most programmers use proportional fonts, and so tools are set up to convert x tabs to y spaces, but I don't think there is a technical connection between the two - certainly not with a non-proportional font and elastic tabstops.

Comment: Except that you've got proportional and fixed the wrong way round, I agree.

Comment: Ah, and I didn't notice until too late to edit it. You are indeed correct.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Unicode.

What did you expect would happen? HT (horizontal tab) has been a whitespace character for decades. The "classic" C-language definition of *white-space* characters consists of the US-ASCII characters:

- `SP`: space (0x20,`' '`)
- `HT`: horizontal tab (0x09,`'\t'`)
- `LF`: line feed (0x0A, `'\n'`)
- `VT`: vertical tab (0x0B, `'\v'`)
- `FF`: vertical tab (0x0C, `'\f'`)
- `CR`: carriage return (0x0C, `'\r'`)

Unicode is a little more...ecumenical in its approach: its definition of *white-space* characters is this set:

- Members of the Unicode category *SpaceSeparator*:

  - `SPACE` (U+0020)
  - `OGHAM SPACE MARK` (U+1680)
  - `MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR` (U+180E)
  - `EN QUAD` (U+2000)
  - `EM QUAD` (U+2001)
  - `EN SPACE` (U+2002)
  - `EM SPACE` (U+2003)
  - `THREE-PER-EM SPACE` (U+2004)
  - `FOUR-PER-EM SPACE` (U+2005)
  - `SIX-PER-EM SPACE` (U+2006)
  - `FIGURE SPACE` (U+2007)
  - `PUNCTUATION SPACE` (U+2008)
  - `THIN SPACE` (U+2009)
  - `HAIR SPACE` (U+200A)
  - `NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE` (U+202F)
  - `MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE` (U+205F)
  - `IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE` (U+3000)
- Members of the Unicode category *LineSeparator*, which consists solely of

  - `LINE SEPARATOR` (U+2028)
- Member of the Unicode category *ParagraphSeparator*, which consists solely of

  - `PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR` (U+2029)
- These Basic Latin/C0 Controls/US-ASCII characters:

  - `CHARACTER TABULATION` (U+0009)
  - `LINE FEED` (U+000A)
  - `LINE TABULATION` (U+000B)
  - `FORM FEED` (U+000C)
  - `CARRIAGE RETURN` (U+000D)
- These C1 Controls and Latin-1 Supplement characters

  - `NEXT LINE` (U+0085)
  - `NO-BREAK SPACE` (U+00A0)

If you don't like the definition, roll your own along these lines (plug in your own character set):

```
public static bool IsNullOrCLanguageWhitespace( this string s )
{
  bool value = ( s == null || rxWS.IsMatch(s) ) ;
  return value ;
}
private static Regex rxWS = new Regex( @"^[ \t\n\v\f\r]*$") ;
```

You might want to add a `char` analog as well:

```
public static bool IsCLanguageWhitespace( this char c )
{
  bool value ;
  switch ( c )
  {
  case ' '  : value = true  ; break ;
  case '\t' : value = true  ; break ;
  case '\n' : value = true  ; break ;
  case '\v' : value = true  ; break ;
  case '\f' : value = true  ; break ;
  case '\r' : value = true  ; break ;
  default   : value = false ; break ;
  }
  return  value ;
}
```

Comment: To my taste, unicode is not very practical here. My current use case was trying to use Unicode categories to differ between horizontal and vertical spaces. But no... I will have to create a lookup table instead of using ``System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)``. Well done, bureaucrats! ;)